# Why SSAS Connection Error (SQL Browse Not Running but it's Running)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, ssis-2012, olap-cube

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The project could not be deployed to the 'OMDA\SQLEXPRESS' server because of the following connectivity problems :
A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.
To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.          0

I made Running to SQL Server Browser And Restart and not work at all